# Use amsplain, but sort by appearance in document, not bibtex file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need to use the amsplain bibliography style (or an identical appearing style), but the sources need to be sorted by order of first appearance in the document, not how they are arranged in the bibtext file. How can I do this?

Comment: All the `unsrt` based styles produce the bibliography in order of appearance in text, but they will resort to the ordering in the `.bib` file if one has `\nocite{*}` in the document (for the remaining entries).

Answer (score 3):

`amsplain.bst` can easily be modified to suppress the sort.

look for the line

```
FUNCTION {presort}
```

and further down,

```
SORT
```

comment out every line, inclusive, in that stretch of code.

then modify the header to acknowledge the file's origin, but remove any indication that ams might be responsible for maintenance or support, and rename the resulting file.  (the lppl didn't exist when the `ams*.bst` files were created, or it would have been applied to this file; if any changes are made in the future, the lppl *will* be used.)